# Mockito:: Null pointer exception for MockMVC exception for MockMVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mockito

I am having project in spring-mvc. I wrote a test case in mockito, Below is the code:

`Cotroller`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/conferences")
public class ConferenceController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConferenceController.class);

    @Autowired
    private ConferenceService conferenceService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Map<String, Object> create(@Valid @RequestBody Conference conference) {
        LOGGER.debug("Creating a new conference with information: {}", conference);

        Map<String, Object> response = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        response.put("message", "Conference created successfully");
        response.put("conference", conferenceService.add(conference));
        return response;
    }
}
```

`Service`

```
@Service
public class ConferenceServiceImpl implements ConferenceService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConferenceServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private ConferenceRepository conferenceRepository;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public Conference add(Conference created) {
        LOGGER.debug("Creating a new conference with information: {}", created);

        created =  conferenceRepository.save(created);
        LOGGER.debug("Added a conference with information: {}", created);

        return created;
    }
}
```

`Test`

```
    @Test
    public void testCreate() throws Exception {
        Conference added = new Conference.Builder("name", "description").build();

        when(conferenceService.add(any(Conference.class))).thenReturn(added);

        mockMvc.perform(post("/api/conferences")
                .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(added))
        )
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.message", is("Conference created successfully")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.conference.id", is(5)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.conference.name", is("name")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.conference.description", is("description")));
    }
```

Below is the error code:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Target object must not be null; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target object must not be null

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:384)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:227)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:436)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.pjwards.aide.service.Conference.ConferenceServiceImpl.add(ConferenceServiceImpl.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.add(Unknown Source)
    at com.pjwards.aide.controller.api.ConferenceControllerTest.testCreate(ConferenceControllerTest.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target object must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setWrappedInstance(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:205)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setWrappedInstance(BeanWrapperImpl.java:138)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setWrappedInstance(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.<init>(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.<init>(BeanWrapperImpl.java:101)
    at org.springframework.data.util.DirectFieldAccessFallbackBeanWrapper.<init>(DirectFieldAccessFallbackBeanWrapper.java:35)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.getId(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:144)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.AbstractEntityInformation.isNew(AbstractEntityInformation.java:51)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.isNew(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:223)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:438)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:468)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.pjwards.aide.service.Conference.ConferenceServiceImpl.add(ConferenceServiceImpl.java:38)
    at com.pjwards.aide.service.Conference.ConferenceServiceImpl$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$2d3321b.CGLIB$add$0(<generated>)
    at com.pjwards.aide.service.Conference.ConferenceServiceImpl$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$2d3321b$$FastClassByMockitoWithCGLIB$$38e6884e.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:216)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.DelegatingMockitoMethodProxy.invokeSuper(DelegatingMockitoMethodProxy.java:19)
    at org.mockito.internal.invocation.realmethod.DefaultRealMethod.invoke(DefaultRealMethod.java:21)
    at org.mockito.internal.invocation.realmethod.CleanTraceRealMethod.invoke(CleanTraceRealMethod.java:30)
    at org.mockito.internal.invocation.InvocationImpl.callRealMethod(InvocationImpl.java:112)
    at org.mockito.internal.stubbing.answers.CallsRealMethods.answer(CallsRealMethods.java:41)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.MockHandlerImpl.handle(MockHandlerImpl.java:93)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.NullResultGuardian.handle(NullResultGuardian.java:29)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.InvocationNotifierHandler.handle(InvocationNotifierHandler.java:38)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.MethodInterceptorFilter.intercept(MethodInterceptorFilter.java:59)
    at com.pjwards.aide.service.Conference.ConferenceServiceImpl$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$2d3321b.add(<generated>)
    ... 47 more
```

Comment: Did you mock all necessary autowired fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this not null pointer exception, you make some thing incorrect
refactor your service

```
@Service
public class ConferenceServiceImpl implements ConferenceService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConferenceServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private ConferenceRepository conferenceRepository;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public Conference add(Conference created) {
        LOGGER.debug("Creating a new conference with information: {}", created);

        LOGGER.debug("Added a conference with information: {}", created);

        return conferenceRepository.save(created);
    }
}
```

and also add your test `Conference`  object id

```
Conference added = new Conference.Builder(5, "name", "description").build();
```